# What does the dot over $x$ or $y$ mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just starting to read up on differential equations. The problem is (in my materials) nowhere is explained what do these dots mean. Can anyone shed some light?

$$\begin{align}&\begin{cases}
\dot x=2x+y ,\\
\dot y=3x+4y. \\
\end{cases} \\
&\begin{cases}
\dot x+x-8y=0, \\
\dot y-x-y=0. \\
\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It usually means derivative with respect to **time**. The notation goes back to [Newton.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation)

By the way, $\ddot{x}$ is often used in Physics for the *second derivative* of $x$ with respect to time.

Comment: so this would be the same as `x'(t)`?

Comment: Yes, if by $x'(t)$ you mean the derivative with respect to time. The dot is kind of "reserved" for derivative with respect to time. In Physics, there will be plenty of derivatives not with respect to time.

Comment: For example, the heat equation can be written $\ddot u=v^2u''$, which is the same as $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=v^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$.